# Accessing a module type's parameters within a network ned file

Tags: omnet++

Suppose I have the following simple module defined in `Client.ned`:

```
simple Client
{
    parameters:
        volatile int xServerCoord = 1;
        volatile int yServerCoord = 2;
}
```

Also suppose that we have the following network defined in `Network.ned`:

```
network Traditional
{
    parameters:
        volatile int xDiff = intuniform(-20,20);
        volatile int yDiff = intuniform(-20,20);
    submodules:
        client: Client {
            parameters:
                xCoord = xServerCoord + xDiff;
                yCoord = yServerCoord + yDiff;
                @display("p=$xCoord,$yCoord");
    };
}
```

When I try to run the simulation, I get the following error:

> Cannot evaluate parameter 'xCoord': (omnetpp::cModule)Traditional: Unknown parameter 'xServerCoord' -- during network initialization

Is it possible for me to read the `xServerCoord` and `yServerCoord` parameters within `Network.ned`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a parameter in NED requires indication of type, for example:

```
parameters:
    int xServerCoord;
    int yServerCoord;
```

It is possible to assign a value of parameter in NED, for example:

```
 parameters:
    int xServerCoord = 1;
```

but one should be aware that this value cannot be later modified, because according to OMNeT++ Manual:

> A non-default value assigned from NED cannot be overwritten later in NED or from ini files; it becomes “hardcoded” as far as ini files and NED usage are concerned. In contrast, default values are possible to overwrite.

The better solution is to assign [default value](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:parameters), for example:

```
 parameters:
    int xServerCoord = default(1);
```

To use a parameter from other module, the name of the module has to be used before the name of parameter.

Therefore the network definition may look like:

```
network Traditional
{
    parameters:
        volatile int xDiff = intuniform(-20,20);
        volatile int yDiff = intuniform(-20,20);
    submodules:
      client: Client {
        parameters:
            client.xServerCoord = client.xServerCoord + xDiff;
            client.yServerCoord = client.yServerCoord + yDiff;

  };
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Also, in my transcription of a simplified version of my code, I forgot to include `volatile int` for the two parameters within `Client.ned`. I edited the code snippets to reflect the true nature of my code.

Comment: I missed it the first time around but this information can be found in A.5.3 of the Simulation Manual